# soql join query in SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm struggling with a query, I want to select all Branches, and 'join' Companies (of type Account) with again the Contacts in there. Until now no luck, what am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
b.Id, b.Location,
  (SELECT FirstName, LastName, FROM b.Companies.Contacts 
    //i've tried combinations of __r and __c
  WHERE City == 'New York')  
FROM Branche__c b
```

my WSDL for this part is built up like this:

```
<complexType name="Branche__c">
  ..
     <element name="Companies__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Account"/>
  ..
</complexType>
..
<complexType name="Account">
  ..
  <element name="Contacts" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
  ..
</complexType>
```

Comment: Is it throwing any kind of error with your SOQL statement, or is it just returning 0 rows?

Comment: @JCD Error is `ERROR at Row:14:Column:24
First SObject of a nested query must be a child of its outer query.`

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is related to a Salesforce limitation that prohibits subqueries on objects that don't have a direct relationship with the parent object. You may need to write this in two separate queries - the first that retrieves Branche__c records and their related Companies__c records, and then another that retrieves the Contact records related to those Companies.

Comment: @JCD yeah i was afraid that would be the problem, this limitation of SF... thnx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about salesforce and should be moved to salesforce beta site of SE

Answer (score 2):

Has a @JCD Told you, this is a Salesforce limitation.

You only can list all Contacts related to Accounts at the same time related to Branches in this way:

```
SELECT Email, Account.Name, 
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId in (
 SELECT Companies__c
   FROM Branche__c
)
```

But if you want to make **join** between those *contacts* and *branches* you should try something like  this:

```
list[] res = new list[]{};
for (Branche__c br : [SELECT Id, Location ,Companies__c FROM Branche__c])
{
     List[] ContactList = [select name, (select email from contacts) from account where id = :br.Companies__c]; 
     res.add(ContactList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "of type Account" do you mean that "Companies" is the label for Accounts?

If so, try this:

```
Select 
  Name, Id, 
  (Select FirstName, LastName From Contacts Where MailingCity = 'New York')
From Account 
Where ID IN (Select CompanyID From Branch__c)
```

Where CompanyID is the API Name of the Account relationship field on Branch__c.

I'm not sure if that will help, but it may be enough to start from.

Also, I'd recommend using the [Force.com Explorer](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/ForceExplorer) to browse the metadata, when writing an SOQL statement, rather than looking through the WSDL.

Comment: The only problem there is that he will not be able to access other Branche__c's fields in the main SELECT. For instance Location